# Website is not looking good on mobile phone

Tags: css, mobile

I am new to CSS/HTML. I have created this website and I want it to look good on mobile phone as well. When I browse the website from my iphone it is scrolled out at max and the text from frow(first row -£20 voucher),srow(second row-at),trow(third row - £4.99) are very small, unreadable. What's wrong?

```
.frow {
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight:900;
}

.srow {
    margin-top:10px;
    line-height:5px;
    font-size: 45px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.trow {
    color:  #FF0000;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #000;
    font-size: 100px;
    font-weight: 900;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to define the meta viewport in order to support mobile devices the way you want:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Include this in your `<head>`.
Modern mobile browsers usually scale the page down, if the viewport doesn't define something else. With the viewport, the page is not scalable (`user-scalable=no`) so it just looks like opened on a small window.

The next step would be, if not already made, making the page usable on small screen resolutions. In order to achieve this, CSS media queries might be helpful.

About the viewport meta tag: http://html5-mobile.de/blog/meta-viewport-fuer-mobile-anpassen

About CSS media queries: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hard coding the length, you can try out twitter bootstrap framework from: http://getbootstrap.com/, which can easily create mobile friendly layout.